# How frequently does OpenSSl RAND_bytes return an error for lack of unpredictability?

Tags: c++, openssl

The documentation for RAND_bytes claims that the function may return an error if the random bytes generated are predictable. My question is how frequent are such errors?

Can calling RAND_bytes in a finite loop (say 5 attempts) and then throw an exception be a reasonable approach around this problem, more or less like this:

```
    unsigned char random_bytes[4];
    uint8_t attempts = 0;
    while(RAND_bytes(random_bytes,sizeof(random_bytes)) != 1 && ++attempts != 5 ) { }
    if( attempts == 5)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("random bytes too predictable after multiple attempts");
    }
```

Or is this loop silly and I should throw after the first attempt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if there is not enough entropy from `/dev/random` (or `/dev/urandom`) then `RAND_bytes` will fail. There is no easy way to determine when the call will fail but it's unlikely.

Comment: Most likely /dev/urandom has enough entropy for the call to not fail. However, it also depends on the number of bytes you are trying to read. If you are using /dev/random - one of the recommended way is to increase the entropy of the source ( so that internally /dev/random generates more random numbers ). For more details: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/entropy.txt

Comment: @VikasGoel: Thank you for this article. Very informative!